# Can you filter a column in size order of an imported HTML? I have tried using query with no success

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importhtml

Using the below `importhtml` I'm hoping to order the numerical data of the third column in size order, but it seems I have lost my way on the model I was following. Any help greatly appreciated.

`=importhtml("https://fbref.com/en/share/SxTNE","table",0)`

`query(IMPORTHTML("https://fbref.com/en/share/SxTNE"”,”table”,2),”Select * where Col3=’Crdy'”)`

Comment: Maybe the problem is caused by the use of typographic quotes like `”` instead of straight quotes like `"`. What is the result returned by QUERY?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

`=query({importhtml("https://fbref.com/en/share/SxTNE","table",0)},"Select Col3")`

There are several reasons why your formula was not successful:

- "special" characters vs "normal" characters: often when formula are copied from the web, they can include characters that are not conventional keyboard characters; they might *look* okay, but the software can't interpret them.

  - `”` vs `"`: `"` is the conventional board character for double quotation marks; whereas `”` is a special character: Right Double Quotation Mark.
  - `’` vs `'`: `'` is a conventional keyboard character for a Single Quotation mark; whereas `’` is a special characters: Right Single Quotation Mark

**Query Data Range**

- `IMPORTHTML("https://fbref.com/en/share/SxTNE"”`: the range ends in two quotations marks (one is a special character). The range should end in one normal Double Quotation mark.
- the `query` range should be surrounded by curly braces to create an array.

**Select where Col3=’Crdy'”**

- `CrdY` is the header for Col3, so `"select * where Col3 = 'CrdY'"` won't return any results (other than the headers) because there are no values in Col3 with a value of "CrdY"

---

**Sample**

This data is returned using this formula:

`=query({importhtml("https://fbref.com/en/share/SxTNE","table",0)})`

[image: Sample]

---

There are several reasons why your formula was not working.